# detect a position of an article, and activate the menu with current class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am making a website in two column, on the left is the menu, on the right is the content.
[Here is a full preview of the website](http://library.rietveldacademie.nl/?page_id=1360) 
When you click a link, the content align itself on the right.
I search for a way to reverse process :
when you scroll on the right, the article you are reading is detect by jquery
 and it activate the link on the left. How could I achieve that ?

[image: A visual explanation]

```
$('.expander').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $('.expander ').removeClass('current');
    $(this).addClass('current');

    var container = $(this).parents('.menu-content').attr('data-id');
    $desc = $(this).parents('.titre-soustitre');

    console.log("click");
    $("#scrollingaside").customScrollbar("scrollByY", $desc.offset().top - ($(window).width() / 100 * 3.6));
    $("#scrollingontheright").customScrollbar("scrollByY", $("#" + container).offset().top - ($(window).width() / 100 * 7.2));




    console.log("");
});

$('.article').click(function(e) {


    var idproj = $(this).find('span:first').attr('id');
    $('.menu-content[data-id="' + idproj + '"]').find('.expander').trigger('click');


});
```

EDIT : A test that doesn't work yet

```
    function checkActiveSection()
{
    var fromTop = jQuery(window).scrollTop() ;
    var idproj = $(this).find('span:first').attr('id');
    jQuery('#scrollingontheright .article').each(function(){
        var sectionOffset = jQuery(this).offset() ;
        if ( sectionOffset.top <= fromTop )
        {

            jQuery('.menu-content[data-id="'+idproj + '"]').addClass('current') ;

        }
    }) ;
}
```

Comment: The effect is called a 'scrollspy'. There's plenty of results if you google.

Comment: Ok, not easy to mix with the design I made, I updated my question with a test, if someone could help me !